# Saving oauth data & using it from database (twitter)

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, laravel

I'm developing a social management service, and within the developing process I'm also learning about many technologies. Here is what I have to write:

1. User have to authenticate with their twitter account
2. After that, in mysql I'm saving those parameters: `oauth_token`, `oauth_verifier` and `oauth_secret`
3. In another file I'm requesting those three parameters from database, and using it in my code.

Problem is that when a user logs out from my site (not from Twitter) and than logs in again I get this error in function `getAccessToken`:

> "Undefined index: oauth_token" in twitter/twitteroauth.php on line 127

And I dont know why? I'm using `Abraham's lib` and `Laravel Framework`.

Here is my code to log in on Twitter:

```
<?php

class Twitter_Controller extends OneAuth\Auth\Controller
{
    function action_index()
    {

// The TwitterOAuth instance
$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('ABCD', 'EFGH');
// Requesting authentication tokens, the parameter is the URL we will be redirected to
$request_token = $twitteroauth->getRequestToken('http://someurl.com/members');

// Saving them into the session
$username = Cookie::get('username');
DB::table('twitter')->where('username', '=', $username)->update(array( 'oauth_token'=>$request_token['oauth_token'],
                                                                   'oauth_secret'=>$request_token['oauth_token_secret']));
//Cookie::put('oauth_token') = $request_token['oauth_token'];
//Cookie::put('oauth_token_secret') = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

// If everything goes well..
if($twitteroauth->http_code==200){
    $oauthtoken = DB::table('twitter')->where('username', '=', Cookie::get('username'))->only('oauth_token');
    $url = $twitteroauth->getAuthorizeURL($oauthtoken);
    header('Location: '. $url);
} else {
    // It's a bad idea to kill the script, but we've got to know when there's an error.
    die('Something wrong happened.');
}


    }
}
```

And here is "main" twitter file (for showing twitter details etc.)

```
    <?php
    $oauthtoken = DB::table('twitter')->where('username', '=', Cookie::get('username'))->only('oauth_token');
    $haveTwitter = DB::table('user')->where('username', '=', Cookie::get('username'))->only('have_tw');
    $oauthsecret = DB::table('twitter')->where('username', '=', Cookie::get('username'))->only('oauth_secret');
    $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('ABCD', 'EFGH',
     $oauthtoken, $oauthsecret);


    echo $haveTwitter;
    if($haveTwitter == '0')
    {
       $access_token=$twitteroauth->getAccessToken(Input::get('oauth_verifier'));
        DB::table('twitter')->where('username', '=', Cookie::get('username'))->update(array('oauth_verifier' => Input::get('oauth_verifier')));
       DB::table('user')->where('username', '=', Cookie::get('username'))->update(array('have_tw' => '1'));
    }
    if($haveTwitter == '1')
    {
        $oauth_verifier = DB::table('twitter')->where('username', '=', Cookie::get('username'))->only('oauth_verifier');
       echo $oauth_verifier;
      $access_token=$twitteroauth->getAccessToken($oauth_verifier);
    }
    $user_info = $twitteroauth->get('account/verify_credentials');
    dd($user_info);
    ?>
```

Variable `$haveTwitter` is to tell if it's the first time the user is logging in on twitter, or if he logged on in Twitter before.

I hope that you understand me (my english is bad) and my code. If you have some problems, please ask, I'll try to explain better.

Answer (score 0):

A guess:

If user logs out, you probably delete the cookie:

```
$username = Cookie::get('username');
```

Then, your database lookup:

```
$oauthtoken = DB::table('twitter')->where('username', '=', Cookie::get('username'))->only('oauth_token');
```

..won't return anything, so your $oauthtoken won't contain data.

If this is not the case, please edit your post a little: what line is 127? What is your logout script doing?